# Batch file for Moving all the pdf files in the subdirectories to a directory "PDF" which is created inside respective subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I created a Batch file to move all the .pdf files in the subdirectories to a folder "PDF" which is created inside the respective subdirectories while running the Batch.
When I run my batch the "PDF" folder is getting created in the subdirectories which is having the .pdf files,but the files are not getting moved to the respective "PDF" folders instead its getting moved to the PDF folder in the ROOT directory.
I have pasted my code below. Please help me over it.

```
FOR /R D:\documentation\DZ_Batcher\FM_Docs\TEST\ %%a in (*.pdf) do (
 md %%~dpaPDF
 move "%%a" "PDF"
)
```

Comment: what if you using the full path again?

Comment: Also, you should check if a file with the same name exists in the target folder (use the full path, as indicated by npocmaka), and exclude the final `PDF` folders of the process, or you will end with a `PDF\PDF\PDF\ ...` chain of folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d /r "D:\documentation\DZ_Batcher\FM_Docs\TEST" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa" neq "PDF" if exist "%%~a\*.pdf" (
    md "%%~a\PDF"
    move "%%a\*.pdf" "%%~a\PDF"
)
```